# Thousands separator in .Net/F#

Tags: .net, f#

What's the recommended way to print an integer with thousands separator? Best I've come up with so far is

```
let thousands(x:int64) = String.Format("{0:0,0}", x)
```

Which works in most cases, but prints zero as 00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let thousands(x:int64) = String.Format("{0:#,0}", x)
```

Answer (score 6):

The formatting token for a decimal place in .NET is "." regardless of the culture that the assembly is using, and "," for the thousand separator. However different cultures (for example France) use "," for decimal places, so that might be an issue to consider.

Here's some (C#) examples:

```
C
£N
£#,#

double x = 67867987.88666;  
Console.WriteLine("{0:C}",x);  
Console.WriteLine("£{0:N}", x);  
Console.WriteLine("£{0:#,#.###}", x);  

Output:  
£67,867,987.89  
£67,867,987.89  
£67,867,987.887
```

[More details here](http://shrinkrays.net/articles/dotnet-formatting-strings.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
let thousands(x:int64) = String.Format("{0:#,###}", x)
```